# How to make an text Hyperlinked using Aspose.Words DOM approach?

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

I am trying to create a Word document using **Aspose.Words for .NET** using the **DOM** approach. How would I make an text hyperlinked?

Like when we click on text it should be route to web page from Docx. 
Example : [click here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by appending a hyperlink field to the paragraph. See the below sample code

```
// Create or load a document
Aspose.Words.Document wordDoc = new Aspose.Words.Document();

// Get first paragraph
Aspose.Words.Paragraph para = wordDoc.FirstSection.Body.FirstParagraph;
para.Runs.Add(new Run(wordDoc, "Visit "));

// Add the hyperlink field to the paragraph
FieldHyperlink field = (FieldHyperlink)para.AppendField(Aspose.Words.Fields.FieldType.FieldHyperlink, false);
// URL
field.Address = @"""http://www.aspose.com""";
// Text
field.Result = "Aspose";
field.Update();

// Set color of the last run
para.Runs[para.Runs.Count - 1].Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

// Save the document
string dst = (dataDir + @"hyperlink.docx");
wordDoc.Save(dst);
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.